# Datetime picker in Chart.js

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I am reading values from mysql and plotting with chart.js. I want to add date selection to the page to be able to plot values between dates and times. My question is ; do I need to write timestamps with the values to the database to be able to read for date selection ?

Answer (score 0):

Just send the date values of your picker via POST (form) to your script. Then extend your MySQL Query with [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php). Then you will get a filtered response for your chart.